# How do I change the font attributes of certain sections of a UILabel text in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

Example:

```
let dummy = UILabel()
dummy.text = "this is a String"
```

I want the view to show something like this. Also, is it possible to change the font size of "String" in dummy?

> this is a **String**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NSAttributedString to do that:

```
let dummy = UILabel()
let theString = "this is a String"
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: theString, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12.0)])
let boldFontAttribute = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(24.0)]

attributedString.addAttributes(boldFontAttribute, range: NSMakeRange(10, theString.characters.count))

dummy.attributedText = attributedString
```

Comment: Nice! This is what I needed.

Comment: If an answer fits your question you can just mark it as "Accepted answer". Happy coding to you !

Comment: Why are so many people downvoting on this?